# How to disable UITapGestureRecognizer when sellect photo from library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm using `UITapGestureRecognizer`

This is my code:

`Home.m`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAnim:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    UIButton *buttontest = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    buttontest.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    buttontest.frame = CGRectMake(0, 80, 40, 40);
    [buttontest addTarget:self action:@selector(test:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:buttontest];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:buttontest];
}
- (void)test: (UIButton*)aButton {
//    TakePhoto *mvc = [[TakePhoto alloc]initWithNibName:@"TakePhoto" bundle:Nil];
//    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mvc animated:YES];
//    
//    [self.view removeFromSuperview];

    if (self.companyController) {
        self.companyController = nil;
    }
    self.companyController = [[TakePhoto alloc] initWithNibName:@"TakePhoto" bundle:nil];
    UIView *viewSuper = [[IQAppDelegate shareInstance] currentVisibleController].view;
    UIViewController *profile = self.companyController;

    profile.view.frame = viewSuper.frame;
    [viewSuper addSubview:profile.view];
    profile.view.frame = CGRectMake(viewSuper.frame.origin.x, viewSuper.frame.size.height, profile.view.frame.size.width, profile.view.frame.size.height);
    [UIView  beginAnimations:nil context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.35];

    profile.view.frame = CGRectMake(viewSuper.frame.origin.x, viewSuper.frame.origin.x, profile.view.frame.size.width, profile.view.frame.size.height);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

}
- (void) tapAnim: (UITapGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {
// Show something
}
```

TakePhoto.m

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    [(UIViewController *)self.delegate presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

I add a view:Takephoto front of Home(i'm not use "push"), like this:

--->Home

--->Take photo (like a popUp show): it has 2 buttons "Choose photo from library" and "Close"

When i use function "Choose photo from gallery", i cant choose a photo and `UITapGestureRecognizer` is always show.

How to disable `UITapGestureRecognizer` when choose photo from gallery?

P/S:sorry about my english.

Comment: did you tried userInteractionEnabled = NO on your viewcontroller.view ?

Comment: yes, i did it. But when set userInteractionEnable = NO, i cant click anything.

Answer (score 1):

Gesture recognizers have the `enabled` property. Set this to `NO` to disable the gesture recognizer. To make this easier you should keep a reference to the tap gesture recognizer using an instance variable.

Comment: i just set enable = no,but i cant click choose photo.

Comment: Update your question with more details (and code) about your "choose photo from gallery" function.

Answer (score 0):

you can set `tapGesture.enabled=NO` before you choose photos.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement this below delegate method :-

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:
 (UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
 shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```

When you look on the documentation it will return YES (by default) to allow the gesture recognizer to examine the touch object, NO to prevent the gesture recognizer from seeing this touch object. For more details follow this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch: